# Is it safe to leave exposed black wire from doorbell transformer?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, doorbell

Is it safe for the time being to leave a loose black electrical wire from my doorbell transformer? (I think this is the transformer based on what I have read)

I tried to push the box into the wall and it didn't quite stay and a wire I think came loose. I think this is a hot wire but I am unsure and do not want to touch it. Is there any issue with leaving this exposed until I can get someone to check it out? The doorbell no longer works so I'm guessing this is the power to it.

[image: loose wire]
[image: close up]

I believe it came out of the red cover which has the other black wires.

Comment: Looks to me like the wires in the wall are all capped off properly, so you'll probably be safe if you get an Electrician out soon.  The loose wire on the transformer, appears to have come loose from the bundle of white wires.

Comment: These pictures seem to show that the low voltage door bell wires from the transformer output enter the same electrical box as the mains wiring. This should be changed as it is not considered safe. There is a reason after all why the mains leads of the transformer on the electrical box cover protrude through the cover whilst the low voltage leads attach to terminals on the transformer on the outside of the box -- specifically to keep then isolated. I suggest that when you get the electrician out that that you look at having the low voltage wires rerouted outside the electrical box.

Comment: @Tester101 so is that black wire coming out likely a neutral wire coming out of the transformer to close the circuit? I thought since its the same color as the one going in that it might be the positive. Neutral going into the white would close the circuit I'm guessing. So that would make sense.

Comment: @MattCarrier Based on the photo, I'd say that the disconnected wire is the "neutral". However, keep in mind that I'm not there, and have no further knowledge of the wiring than what you've provided.

Comment: @Tester101 I had it fixed tonight and you were correct on the wiring. It belonged in the grouping of white wires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not safe.

I would turn off power to that circuit at the distribution panel, test the wire with a suitable voltage detecter/meter and insulate the end of the wire until the whole repair can be completed.

If you can't do this and the house is occupied, I would treat it as a serious life-threatening hazard. I would prevent all access to that room, by fitting a lock if necessary.

Comment: Thanks I shut off the lights to the house and checked the outlets in the affected room and they are all off. I don't have a meter to check to see if it is hot. I'll call an electrician in the morning. I'm not sure if the doorbell is on the same breaker as lights.